# List passed to action method has no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, actionmethod

I am passing a generic list of objects from a view page to an action method via an action link.  The action link looks like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Foo", new { a = Model.A })
```

The action method signature is

```
public ActionResult Foo(List<foo> a)
```

The problem is that when I run this code in the debugger I can clearly see that there are two elements in this List in the view but when the execution reaches the action method there are no elements in the list.  Why might this be?

It's been suggested that I "post to ActionResult".  What does this mean?  If it is the solution then great.

Comment: It is the property of the model of the view that is of type List<foo> and it is the thing that contains 2 elements.

Comment: You can't pass lists of complex types like that, you'll either have to A) pass it basic parameters you need to repopulate the list or B) instead of an action link, post to said ActionResult.

Comment: Ok I think I understand A).  I tried to pass it IOrderedQueryable<A> but I got a weird error about an interface not being able to be instantiated or something like that.  I don't understand what you mean by B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, which will pass the elements as ?a[0]=foo&a[1]=bar&a[2]=hello

```
@{
    var dict = new RouteValueDictionary();
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.A.Count; i++)
    {
        dict.Add("a[" + i + "]", Model.A[i]);
    }
}
@Html.ActionLink("Click here", "Foo", dict);
```

Comment: The problem is that there are a lot of values and there are some values that themselves are complex types so that I guess I would need a RouteValueDictionary within a RouteValueDictionary.  Is there no simpler way to do this that doesn't pollute the url so much.  Could I use TempData?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you're just trying to hold a significant amount of state between requests, you might want to consider either storing it in a cookie, or create a form with hidden fields and POST the data to yourself (which is what @mattytommo meant as option B).

Comment: Well, here is what I'm trying to do.  The actionlink is a link that a user clicks to export data in a table into csv format.  For this to happen I need the rows in the table from which to get the data from.  Now, I can't generate those rows in my Action method since the same method will be used by multiple tables meaning there will be multiple different queries.

Comment: Ok. It seems to me that you should be able to refetch that data from the Action method. Yes, the tables all share the same method, but you must have some kind of information to differentiate the tables. Do they display different dates? Different data types? Different users? Whatever the differentiating factor is, just pass that and have your server fetch the data.

Comment: well I have thought of a dirty way of doing it.  I could pass in a string and then say if(s == "open") get this data else if (s== "closed") get that data else if (s=="coming soon") get another type of data and so on.  Very dirty though.

Comment: Not really. Maybe pass an enum or a numerical id instead, but that's really not dirty at all. It's a whole lot less dirty than passing all the data in the query string :)
Where did the data come from in the first place? If you're rendering these tables you must have some way of differentiating that data.